# Last value gets printed instead of each iteration value in for loop while reading file from JSON and looping through it

Tags: javascript, json, loops, closures

In the below example we read from a JSON data and store it in a variable.
Then we loop through it to print out the value of each of its iteration.

I have "cartList.innerHTML" which will list out "Edit" 4 times as that is the number of the objects in the array. Like below

Edit

Edit

Edit

Edit

Once you click on the first Edit a modal should open and display the name of the first object, on clicking the second edit the name of the second and so on.

But for some reason the value remains to be the name of the last object for each Edit. How do I get it to print the correct name for each edit.

```
// Fetch JSON data
function loadJSON(file, callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', file, true); // Refers to JSON file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
}

function load() {
    loadJSON("assets/cart.json", function(response) {
        var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(actual_JSON);

        var cartList = document.getElementById("cart-products");
        var itemObj = actual_JSON.productsInCart;       
        var itemLength = actual_JSON.productsInCart.length;

        // Loop through JSON data
        for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {

            (function(i) {
                /* Output Link Element with Edit text & on click
                   display a modal containing current value of iteration */

                cartList.innerHTML += '<div>'+
                                      '<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn btn-outline button-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Edit</a>'+
                                      '</div>';

                var editCartModal = document.getElementById("edit-cart");
                editCartModal.innerHTML = itemObj[i].p_name;// Name of the current object

            })(i);              

        // for loop ends here
        }

    })
}
load(); // Loads function on page load
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because though you are running the following code in an IIFE:

```
var editCartModal = document.getElementById("edit-cart");
editCartModal.innerHTML = itemObj[i].p_name;// Name of the current object
```

You're just modifying the same modal (`getElementById()`) four times.

A simple answer to fix this would be adding a `data` attribute:

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {

    (function(i) {
         /* Output Link Element with Edit text & on click
            display a modal containing current value of iteration */

        cartList.innerHTML += '<div>'+
                              '<a href="javascript: void(0);"' +  
                                  'class="btn btn-outline button-edit" data-toggle="modal"' + 
                                  'data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-custom-value="' + i + 
                                  '">Edit</a>'+
                              '</div>';
    })(i);              

    // for loop ends here
}

/* ES5 way*/
/*
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('button-edit');
list.forEach(function(){
    ...
})
*/

[...document.getElementsByClassName('button-edit')].map(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var chosenIdx = this.dataset.customValue;
        var editCartModal = document.getElementById("edit-cart");
        editCartModal.innerHTML = itemObj[chosenIdx].p_name;// Name of the current object
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Hi @kevlai22... Thank you for your answer... It still doesn't work for me for some reason... It shows an error

"document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function"

Please can you try it in a fiddle using a sample JSON to see if it works?

Comment: Oh, I made a simple mistake. `document.getElementsByClassName('button-edit')` gives you a node list. Already edited the answer

Comment: Hey kevlai22... Thank you so much for your continuous answers... Isn' t that ES6? How would we be able to do it in ES5?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Thank you @kevlai22... I'm a complete newbie to javascript... Please can you tell me what should be done inside the for each
/*
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('button-edit');
list.forEach(function(){
    // What should be done here?
})
*/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every function inside the `for` loop begins to execute after the loop ends. It's the same behavior as for callbacks. When you call each `(function(i) {})(i)` they all go to the end of function call stack, and only after last iteration of the loop they start executing (with the last `i` value).

I'm curious why do you need an internal *inline* function at all? Why don't just put this code directly to the loop body?